# Eliminar caracteres después de un símbolo, dentro de una lista

Tags: python, lista, caracteres

necesito limpiar una lista para que quede solo la primera oracion antes de la primera coma (son strings), en cada uno de los items de la lista, por ejemplo:

```
x = ["inagural 324, valencia, españa", "rodeo 324 el canto, barcelona, españa", "fisco 654, ramon, amparo, españa"]
```

y de resultado asi:

```
x = ["inagural 324", "rodeo 324 el canto", "fisco 654"]
```

si me pudieran ayudar, estaría muy agradecido

Comment: Recuerda que en esta comunidad apoyamos siempre y cuando tengas avances hechos, no hacemos el trabajo por ti. Agrega el código que has intentado y te orientamos que estas haciendo mal. De forma contraria, te aconsejaría contrates un consultor de desarrollo.

Comment: `nueva_lista = [frase.split(",")[0] for frase in x]`

Answer (score 2):

lo logre, usando un separador:

```py
x = ["inagural 324, valencia, españa", "rodeo 324 el canto, barcelona, españa", "fisco 654, ramon, amparo, españa"]

sep = ','
x2 = [item.split(sep, 1)[0] for item in x]

x2 = ['inagural 324', 'rodeo 324 el canto', 'fisco 654']
```